# Do UPSERT based on specific value of JSON in Postgres 10

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, upsert, postgresql-10

I have a Postgres table `messages` as follows:

```
Column   |           Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    
-----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------
 id        | integer                  |           | not null |
 message   | jsonb                    |           |          | 
 date      | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
```

```
id | message                      | date
1  | {"name":"alpha", "pos":"x"}  | 2020-02-11 12:31:44.658667+00
2  | {"name":"bravo", "pos":"y"}  | 2020-02-11 12:32:43.123678+00
3  | {"name":"charlie", "pos":"z"}| 2020-02-11 12:38:37.623535+00
```

What I would like to do is do an UPSERT based on the value of the `name` key i.e., if there is an insert with same `name` value, then the other value `pos` is updated, otherwise a new entry is created.

I did `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX message_name ON messages((message->>'name'));`

I found the [INSERT ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html) in Postgres 9.5+ but I can't understand how to use the unique index with this.

I don't know if this is the correct approach to do it in the first place so if there is a better way to do this, I would appreciate the input.

Comment: If the name is such an important attribute of the message, it shouldn't be hidden in the JSON value, but should be a column of its own in the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to repeat the expression from the index:

```
insert into messages (message)
values ('{"name":"alpha", "pos":"new pos"}')
on conflict ((message->>'name')) 
  do update 
     set message = jsonb_set(messages.message, '{pos}'::text[], excluded.message -> 'pos', true)
;
```

If you have more keys in the JSON and want to replace (or add) all of them, you can use this:

```
insert into messages (message)
values ('{"name":"alpha", "pos":"new pos", "some key": 42}')
on conflict ((message->>'name')) 
  do update 
     set message = messages.message || (excluded.message - 'name')
;
```

Comment: `message = messages.message || (excluded.message - 'name')` what is the meaning of this part?

Comment: `(excluded.message - 'name')` simply removes the `name` key from the provided value, thus replacing/appending all other keys to the existing value in the table. In theory you could also just write `messages.message || excluded.message` to append/overwrite the existing values with the provided values